# Does sequelize have an equivalent of mysqls replace function?

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

The question is self-explanatory.

Replace: works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted

So the query i'd like to run is

```
REPLACE INTO questions SET question = 'myquestions', category = 'mycategory', isNew = '0';
```

and my table is the following

```
CREATE TABLE questions (
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
question varchar(254) NOT NULL,
category varchar(254) NOT NULL,
isNew tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE KEY (category, isNew)
);
```

So the goal is if there is already a row with the same category AND isNew delete it before creating the new row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the UPSERt function

[See documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-upsert)

> Insert or update a single row. An update will be executed if a row which matches the supplied values on either the primary key or a unique key is found. Note that the unique index must be defined in your sequelize model and not just in the table. Otherwise you may experience a unique constraint violation, because sequelize fails to identify the row that should be updated.

```
  Model.upsert({uniqueKey: 1234, name: 'DarthVader'}).then(function () {
  });
```